# Int value not being passed with object even though get/set methods are used

Tags: c#

I'm sorry if my headline is confusing, but I didn't know how to express my problem differently. I have 2 classes, both windows forms; one of them is a login interface, and the other is a shop interface that the user is taken to if his login is valid. Now, I'm trying to pass the username and password along to the shop interface class so I can subtract "purchases" from the correct row in the database, but for some reason this is not working. I have tested my method with just passing valid username and password strings directly through the code, and if I do that, the method works fine. Debug mode too shows that the value of the username and password is not passed along to the shop interface class through the get methods. Hope you can help, thanks in advance, and sorry for the quite big block of text :)

Here are the two classes in question, plus the class with the methods that I am using for the database:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ShopshopFinalfinal
{
    public partial class LoginInterface : Form
    {
        DatabaseConnection dbConnection = new DatabaseConnection();
        private ShopInterface shop1Interface;
        private RegisterInterface reg1Interface;
        private string _username;
        private string _password;

        public void SetUsername(string username)
        {
            _username = username;
        }

        public void SetPassword(string password)
        {
            _password = password;
        }

        public string GetUsername()
        {
            return _username;
        }

        public string GetPassword()
        {
            return _password;
        }


        public LoginInterface()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            txt_password.PasswordChar = '*';
        }

        private void btn_login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (dbConnection.CheckUsername(txt_username.Text) == 1 && dbConnection.CheckPassword(txt_password.Text) == 1)
            {
                SetUsername(txt_username.Text);
                SetPassword(txt_password.Text);
                //txt_username.Clear();
                //txt_password.Clear();
                shop1Interface = new ShopInterface();
                shop1Interface.Show();

            }
        }

        private void btn_register_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           reg1Interface = new RegisterInterface();
            reg1Interface.Show();
        }
    }
}


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ShopshopFinalfinal
{
    public partial class ShopInterface : Form
    {

        private DatabaseConnection dbConnection = new DatabaseConnection();
        private LoginInterface login = new LoginInterface();



        public ShopInterface()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btn_buyapple_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            //string username = login.GetUsername();
            //string password = login.GetPassword();

            dbConnection.Transaction(login.GetUsername(), login.GetPassword(), 10);


        }
    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ShopshopFinalfinal
{
    class DatabaseConnection
    {
        private SqlConnection conn;
        private SqlDataReader rdr;
        private SqlCommand cmd;

        public DatabaseConnection()
        {
            conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.connectionstring);
        }

        public int CheckUsername(string username)
        {
            int result = 0;

            //Opret den ønskede SQL kommmando - her tjekker den om username fra textboxen er lig en i User table.
            cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from dbo.Users where Username ='" + username + "'", conn);

            //Åbn forbindelsen til databasen.
            conn.Open();

            //Udfører det ønskede SQL statement på databasen.
            rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            //Tjek om den har læst og om det er rigtigt.
            if (rdr.Read())
            {
                result = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                result = 0;
            }

            //Luk forbindelsen til databasen.
            conn.Close();

            return result;
        }

        public int CheckPassword(string password)
        {
            int result = 0;

            //Opret SQL-kommando - tjek om password fra textbox er lig med et i databasen.
            cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from dbo.Users where Password ='" + password + "'", conn);

            //Åben forbindelsen.
            conn.Open();

            //Udfør det ønskede SQL statement på databasen.
            rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (rdr.Read())
            {
                result = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                result = 0;
            }

            conn.Close();

            return result;

        }

        public void RegisterUser(string username, string password)
        {
            conn.Open();

            cmd =
                new SqlCommand("insert into dbo.Users (Username, Password, IsAdmin, Balance) values ('" +
                               username +
                               "', '" + password + "', '0', '0')", conn); 
            rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            rdr.Close();
            conn.Close();
        }

        public void Transaction(string username, string password, int price)
        {


            conn.Open();

            cmd = new SqlCommand("update dbo.Users set Balance = Balance - " + price + " where Username = '"+username+"' and Password = '"+password+"'", conn);

            rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            rdr.Close();

            conn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When passing data between forms you must use an instance of the form.  See my two form project example : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975508/reach-control-from-another-page-asp-net

Comment: Thanks mate, works perfectly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there but you are not passing the data to the other form. Change this in `ShopInterface`:

```
private LoginInterface login = new LoginInterface();
```

to this:

```
public LoginInterface Login {get; set;}
```

Then in your `LoginInterface` do this before you show the `shop1Interface`:

```
private void btn_login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dbConnection.CheckUsername(txt_username.Text) == 1 && dbConnection.CheckPassword(txt_password.Text) == 1)
    {
        SetUsername(txt_username.Text);
        SetPassword(txt_password.Text);
        //txt_username.Clear();
        //txt_password.Clear();
        shop1Interface = new ShopInterface();

        // This is the line you need
        shop1Interface.Login = this;

        shop1Interface.Show();

    }
}
```

Now because you passed a reference to your `LoginInterface` to `shop1Interface`, you can now access it like this:

```
private void btn_buyapple_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Now it will work
    string username = this.Login.GetUsername();
    string password = this.Login.GetPassword();

    dbConnection.Transaction(login.GetUsername(), login.GetPassword(), 10);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have the `ShopInterface` creating a brand new instance of `LoginInterface`, which would have all of its properties in their default state. This is not the same instance as the one that actually has the values, hence why they are blank.

I think that rather than trying to find a way to get `ShopInterface` to take the values from a `LoginInterface` (which would mean a strong dependency from `ShopInterface` to `LoginInterface`), a better approach would be to provide a way to pass them in:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ShopshopFinalfinal
{
    public partial class ShopInterface : Form
    {

        private DatabaseConnection dbConnection = new DatabaseConnection();
        private string Username { get; set; }
        private string Password { get; set; }

        public ShopInterface(string username, string password)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Username = username;
            Password = password;
        }

        private void btn_buyapple_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            dbConnection.Transaction(username, password, 10);


        }
    }
}
```

Then you can have the `LoginInterface` do this:

```
shop1Interface = new ShopInterface(txt_username.Text, txt_password.Text);
shop1Interface.Show();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is probably a good idea so I don't have them create instances of each other all the time!